# How can I update a friends list with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, contacts

I'm trying to create a simple contacts function for my Android app.  My JSON tree is structured like this:

```
User
- UserId
    - Username
    - DisplayName
    - PhotoURL
    - Contacts
         - UserId1
         - UserId2
         - UserId3
```

Using the UserId under contacts, I can retrieve the relevant information. I'm currently trying to store this information in an offline SQL database (I'm open to other suggestions) so that I can quickly query contacts and their information when offline.

```
   UserID | Username | DisplayName | PhotoURL
```

My issue is that if I were to put a listener (either Child or Value) onto Contacts for each user, I end up having to return the entire Contacts table everytime if my app goes offline back to online, or when I start the activity. I can't find a way to find out which contact exactly was changed, meaning I have to download all contacts again to repopulate my entire SQL table. For scalability, I can't keep doing this as Contacts for each User can get large.  In addition, DisplayName and PhotoURL is most likely to constantly change.  If I add a listener, I'd once again be constantly downloading the entire Contacts table as there's no way to find exactly which contact has changed their name or photo.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!